# The meaning of 3 axis values of magnetometer

Tags: sensors

Could someone explain to me the meaning of 3 axis x, y & z of Magnetometer

Comment: This isn't Android-specific, and [general](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetometer) [reference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth%27s_magnetic_field).

Answer (score 7):

The magnetic field of a certain point is directional and has magnitude. The x,y,z returned by the sensor is a **vector** that describes the strength and direction of the magnetic field relative to the device measured in microtesla.

For example, a value of `(x, y, z) = (50, 50, 0)` means that there is a magnetic field `sqrt(50**2+50**2+0**2) ≈ 70.7107` microtesla strong in the direction of 45 degree to X-axis and Y-axis of the device.